# Why doesn't this function run when the reactive variable changes value?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, reactive-programming

I'm new to meteor and I'm trying to get a hang of the whole reactivity thing.

There isn't a specifc reason why I want this function to re-run, in fact, it not re-running is actually the desired behavior for my use case. I just want to know why this is happening so I can better understand the concepts.

If I add a function as a property on a template instance, like this:

```
Template.services.onCreated( function() {
    this.templates = [
        "web_design",
        "painting",
        "gardening"
    ];
    this.current_index = new ReactiveVar(0);

    this.determineSlideDirection = function() {
        console.log(this.current_index.get());
    };
});
```

And then I update the reactive var in response to some event.

```
Template.services.events({
    'click .nav-slider .slider-item': function(event, template) {
        var new_selection = event.currentTarget;
        template.current_index.set($(new_selection).index());
    }
});
```

The function is not re-run upon the invocation of the `set()` call.

However, If I have a *helper* that utilizes the variable, it will be re-run.

```
Template.services.helpers({
    currentTemplate: function() {
        var self = Template.instance();
        return self.templates[self.current_index.get()];
    }
});
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive data sources only cause some functions to automatically re-run. These functions are:

- `Tracker.autorun`
- `Template.myTemplate.helpers({})`
- `Blaze.render` and `Blaze.renderWithData`

In your code above you would want to use `Tracker.autorun`

```
Template.services.onCreated( function() {
    this.templates = [
        "web_design",
        "painting",
        "gardening"
    ];

    this.current_index = new ReactiveVar(0);

    Tracker.autorun(function(){
        // actually, this might not work because the context of
        // 'this' might be changed when inside of Tracker.
        this.determineSlideDirection = function() {
            console.log(this.current_index.get());
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: `Tracker.autorun` is also commonly mistyped as `Tracker.autofun` because it gives you automatic FUN!